# Swift Extra argument "width" in call in CGRect

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I am trying to add a few buttons in the code
and i get an error "Extra argument "width" in call"

```
        let yPos = txt.frame.origin.y + txt.frame.height


    for i in 0..<count {
        let yt : Int = i*40 + yPos
        //let b = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: xPos, y: 40, width: 100, height: 30))
        var b = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: xPos, y: yt, width: 100, height: 30))
        b.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "test:"))
        b.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        b.tag = i
        self.addSubview(b)
    }
```

I cant figure out what is the problem.
I tried to cast all the argument to Int but i get the same error.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

my mistake i had to cast all the arguments to CGFloat

```
       for i in 0...2 {
        let yt : CGFloat = CGFloat(i*40) + yPos
        //let b = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: xPos, y: 40, width: 100, height: 30))
        var b = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: xPos, y: yt, width: 100, height: 30))
        b.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "test:"))
        b.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        b.tag = i
        self.addSubview(b)
    }
```